# Why are the attributes of this model initialized to null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This is a follow up to the questions [Custom form data with multiple files to Web API controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627437/custom-form-data-with-multiple-files-to-web-api-controller/35637230#35637230) and [Filling Parameter with Attribute [FromForm] with Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671769/filling-parameter-with-attribute-fromform-with-fiddler/45671864#45671864), which are both answered by citing [A MediaTypeFormatter for WebApi for multipart/form-data including file uploads](https://gist.github.com/Danielku15/bfc568a19b9e58fd9e80).

Essentially this is the same question Tocana has asked before in the last link.

I copied the code from the latter, registered the media type formatter and tried it with fiddler, but as it enters `UploadController.Post(UploadRequestViewModel model)` model is instanciated but its attributes are all equal to `null`.

I debugged it and found that `FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter.BindToModel(IDictionary<string, object> data, Type type, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)` is called with a correct `data` dictionary, but from then on I cannot make head from tails. The binder used to bind the model is `CompositeModelBinder`, but wether that is correct or not I cannot tell.

The fiddler request looks like this:

*Header:*

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------acebdf13572468
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:49473
Content-Length: 13192
```

*Body*

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SiteId"
Content-Type: text/plain

987654321
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="StartDate"
Content-Type: text/plain

24.08.1979
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Zulu"; filename="ExifTest.tif"
Content-Type: image/tiff

<@INCLUDE *C:\...\ExifTest.tif*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

What do I have to do to get my model correctly initialized, i.e. its values are not `null`?

**EDIT:**
All models and controllers are those of [A MediaTypeFormatter for WebApi for multipart/form-data including file uploads](https://gist.github.com/Danielku15/bfc568a19b9e58fd9e80), i.e.

*Model:*

```
public class UploadRequestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller:*

```
[Route("UploadTest")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(UploadRequestViewModel model)
{
}
```

*FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter.BindToModel*

```
private object BindToModel(IDictionary<string, object> data, Type type, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
{
    if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
    if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

    using (var config = new HttpConfiguration())
    {
        // if there is a requiredMemberSelector set, use this one by replacing the validator provider
        var validateRequiredMembers = RequiredMemberSelector != null && formatterLogger != null;
        if (validateRequiredMembers)
        {
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(ModelValidatorProvider), new RequiredMemberModelValidatorProvider(RequiredMemberSelector));
        }

        // create a action context for model binding
        var actionContext = new HttpActionContext
        {
            ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext
            {
                Configuration = config,
                ControllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor
                {
                    Configuration = config
                }
            }
        };

        // create model binder context 
        var valueProvider = new NameValuePairsValueProvider(data, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var metadataProvider = actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Services.GetModelMetadataProvider();
        var metadata = metadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(null, type);
        var modelBindingContext = new ModelBindingContext
        {
            ModelName = string.Empty,
            FallbackToEmptyPrefix = false,
            ModelMetadata = metadata,
            ModelState = actionContext.ModelState,
            ValueProvider = valueProvider
        };

        // bind model 
        var modelBinderProvider = new CompositeModelBinderProvider(config.Services.GetModelBinderProviders());
        var binder = modelBinderProvider.GetBinder(config, type);
        var haveResult = binder.BindModel(actionContext, modelBindingContext);

        // log validation errors 
        if (formatterLogger != null)
        {
            foreach (var modelStatePair in actionContext.ModelState)
            {
                foreach (var modelError in modelStatePair.Value.Errors)
                {
                    if (modelError.Exception != null)
                    {
                        formatterLogger.LogError(modelStatePair.Key, modelError.Exception);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        formatterLogger.LogError(modelStatePair.Key, modelError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return haveResult ? modelBindingContext.Model : GetDefaultValueForType(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller action code?

Comment: "of this model"? Which model? Did you forget to post some code?